# JQuery run effect without doubleclicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Here is the code, I'm using in the theme and I want to be able to click once and the link
The Latest pulls up after click not for it to callback.

```
<script>
jQuery( "li#menu-item-28 a" ).click(function() {
  jQuery( "div#the-latest.bg div.container" ).slideToggle( "slide" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Specially, the "double-clicking" relevant part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure that I understand your question but try:

```
<script>
    jQuery( "li#menu-item-28 a" ).live("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery( "div#the-latest.bg div.container" ).slideToggle( "slide" );
    });
</script>
```

event.preventDefault() prevents the default event which happens when the link is clicked.

Comment: how can you make the .slideToggle delay for 5 seconds

Comment: setTimeout(function() { $("div#the-latest.bg div.container").fadeOut(); }, 5000); is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **live**  binding for this. Check the code. That may be helpful.

```
<script>
jQuery( "li#menu-item-28 a" ).live('click',function() {
  jQuery( "div#the-latest.bg div.container" ).slideToggle( "slide" );
});
</script>
```